# Custom Refinement Panel option on People Search returns no results

Tags: search-results, people-search

I am creating a staff list for the company and have set up an Enterprise Search Center and all is working great.  I would like the refinement panel to list the Departments in the company so people can quickly and easy filter by department.

I have added the following to the Filter Category Definition in the refinement panel:

```
<Category Title="Department" Description="Use this filter to restrict results by department" Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="3" NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="20" MaxNumberOfFilters="20" SortBy="Name" SortDirection="Ascending" ShowMoreLink="False" MappedProperty="Department" />
```

Which shows a list of our departments in the refinement panel - great!  Problem is, when I click on any department I get no results returned, rather than seeing the people in that department.

The URL after clicking on one of the departments is:

```
http://domain/sites/Search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?r=department%3D%22Accounts%22
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you, this is driving me nuts!

Comment: ..otherwise your search for People works fine? (i mean you have in Content Source SPS3://mySitesLocation as a source, right?) and it does return results, besides that - follow Deepu's link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create the mapped property "Department" mentioned in the refinement panel? If not, create the mapped property and perform a full crawl again. Follow the instructions in [this post](http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2011/08/customizing-the-people-search-refinement-panel/) which does the same.

Good Luck .

Comment: I was using the built in 'Department' managed property.  Once I created my own according to these instructions it all worked.  Not sure what the difference is, but that you for a link to a great article.

Comment: Well, that's weird, but I have the same issue with O365. Any ideas to get it solved on O365 account?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while trying to use the default Department field as a refinement filter, once I set "Allow this property to be used in scopes" on the Managed Property it started working.

Comment: Interestingly, I was having the same problem using the default "CreatedBy" managed property as a refinement filter - the filter would show the available options (and counts), but selecting a filter yielded no results.  Setting "Allow...in scopes" and recrawling fixed it, so +1 for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ari Bakker wrote a blog that walks you through the entire process of what your trying to accomplish here: http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-people-directory/

He even points out the issue with the department property. You could always make the department proerty a managemend metadata property and it will automatically get addeded to the refinement panel. :)