# Refinement Panel Web Part/SharePoint 2010 with custom category based on a multi-choice column

Tags: search-results, refinement-panel

I'm supposed to modify the search refiner web part (Refinement Panel-SharePoint 2010) to add a custom category based on a multi-choice column that is basically attached to sites and pages (not to items or documents)!

After the modifications the new category shows up in the refiners at the search result page and actually shows the number of results in each refiner as shown in pic below:

[image]

But when i click on let's say "Filter 1" i get this message "**We did not find any results for (the given search word)**"

**Reset Index** & **Full Crawl** did NOT resolve the issue! Here is the added XML to the **Filter Category Definition** field of the **Refinement Panel** web part:

```
<Category    Title="Site Subject"    Description="Managed metadata of the pages"    Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator"    MetadataThreshold="1"    NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="3"    MaxNumberOfFilters="20"    ShowMoreLink="True"    MappedProperty="Managed property name"    MoreLinkText="show more"    LessLinkText="show fewer" ShowCounts="Count" />
```

Any help would be appriciated :-) Thanks in advance

Eliya Amanoeel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you may not want or need to use that managed property as part of a scope definition, try enabling "Allow this property to be used in scopes" on your managed property, and then re-crawling (full).

I was seeing similar behavior (filters show up, with counts, but when used provide no results) when trying to use the OOB "CreatedBy" field as a refinement filter category.  Enabling "Allow...to be used in scopes" worked for my problem, but I'm not exactly sure why.

I decided to give that solution a try after stumbling across this [other question regarding similar behavior.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/custom-refinement-panel-option-on-people-search-returns-no-results/43799)

(If anyone can shed light on to why this happens, or why the solution works, I'd be interested to learn about it.)

Comment: Mr Dylan, thanks for your effort! I could resolve the issue through your tips and the link you provided.